# Hive vs. HiveContext

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive, pyspark, hiveql

I have an RDD of ~100,000 records in the following format: `(key, value)`.

For a function `def f(x, y): ... return z`, I need the following cartesian product: `(key1, key2, z)` where `key1 <> key2` and `z = f(value1, value2)`, from which I'll get the equivalent of `SELECT key1, key2, z, RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY value1 ORDER BY z DESC) AS rnk`.

My question is, is it more efficient to get the rank in Spark using HiveContext window functions, or is it better to output this to a Hive table and run the equivalent HiveQL query? Window functions on Spark would need to repartition due to the `.rank()`.

Comment: No matter what you do here Cartesian product is much bigger issue than a repartition and Spark  < 2.0 is using Hive Window functions so there should be no significant difference between these two.

Comment: @zero323  No fun to answer spark questions anymore. You're always there first (and with good answers).